# Regex in R to detect combinations of three words and variations of those words

Tags: r, regex

I am not very experienced in regex so I am reaching out. Please point me towards other responses in case this is a duplicate question.

My string contains three words that are grouped. These three words may occur in any order within each group.
The words represent a part number and their revision, possibly with the occurrence of variations of the word "rev" (short for: revision). The revision may also not be present.
Two of the three words belong together: if there are two 7 digit numbers, there must be two revisions!

Business background: we have an engineering change database and some changes only contain the part number of the part that is changing. The associated revisions are in a description field. Typically the description contains the part number and the revision amongst other text.
I need to work out the revisions of the parts from the description.

**Match**
I need to return the part number(s) and their associated revision(s).

**Words**

- 7 digits, e.g. 1234567
- Variations of the word "REV": REV, Rev, rev, Rev. etc) with a length of 3 or 4 characters (if 4 characters then the 4th character is always a dot). This word is optional.
- One letter followed by 2 digits: e.g. A00, B02, C00
  The 7 digit word (1234567) and the revision (AOO) ALWAYS occur in pairs possibly in mixed order. The acronym "REV" and its variations are optional.

**Simple and most common case**

Just one occurrence of the three words in any order. There can be spaces between the words but also a comma, a colon, other text or combinations thereof. "REV" and variations are optional.

**More complex case**

The 3 words occur multiple times as groups in mixed order. Examples of real world combinations:

- 1234567 Rev A00 7654321 B00 Rev C00 1357913 1337335 Rev A00, 1337336
- 1234567 Rev A00 *some random text* 7654321 B00 Rev C00 1357913 1337335 Rev A00
- 1337336 Rev A00, 1337338 Rev. A00, and 1337339 REV A00
- 1281660 A01, 1281661 B00,1281839 A01
- A01 1281660 1281661 B00 A01 1281839
- Rev A01 1281660, REV. B00 1281661, 1281839 A01

But combinations that break the groups are not possible. For instance:

- 1281660 1281661 Rev A01 Rev B00
- Rev A00, Rev B00, 1234567, 7654321
- 1234567 Rev A00 7654321 B00 C00

are not possible (and if they would I want to ignore them). In other words: if there is a 7 digit string, it must be followed by a revision. If there are two 7 digit strings  next to each other, there must be a revision before and after. etc.

I hope this is clear enough.
Happy to use `base` regex or e.g. `stringr` functions.
Your help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
Some more clarification, using parentheses to indicate groups and using letter A (7 digit string), B (the string "REV" and variations) and C (A00) to indicate the words. Realistic combinations with the note that A and C must be present in a group:

- (A B C) or (C B A) or (B A C) or (A C) or (C A) etc. B is optional.
- (A B C)(C B A) or (A C)(B A C) or (C B A)(A C) or (A C)(C B A)
- (A C)(C A)(A C)
- etc.

Impossible combinations:

- (A A B)
- (B A) or (B A)
- (A B B)(A C)
- etc.

An occurrence of A must see a C within the same group. An A can not be associated with more than one B or C. I guess this problem could be simplified if we would ignorer B altogether.

Comment: For the more complex cases, can you post what the correct groupings are? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I added some further clarifications.

Comment: Your 1st "complex case" appears to have the following groupings: `1234567 Rev A00 / 7654321 B00 Rev / C00 1357913 / 1337335 Rev A00 /, 1337336`. Please explain the appearance of that lonely `1337336` at the end. What return value (object) would you want for this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the approach you take, I suggest you begin by doing some simple pre-processing, in two steps.

First remove `Rev` and its variations and other extraneous text. You could do that by replacing matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
(?![A-Z]\d{2}\b)[^\d\s]+
```

This regex performs the following operations.

```
(?!       : begin a negative lookahead
  [A-Z]   : match an uppercase letter
  \d{2}   : match 2 digits
  \b      : assert a word boundary
)         : end negative lookahead
[^\d\s]+  : match 1+ characters other than digits and whitespace
```

That would convert your "real-world matches" to the following strings.

```
1234567  A00 7654321 B00  C00 1357913 1337335  A00
1234567  A00    7654321 B00  C00 1357913 1337335  A00
1337336  A00 1337338  A00  1337339  A00
1281660 A01 1281661 B00 1281839 A01
A01 1281660 1281661 B00 A01 1281839
 A01 1281660  B00 1281661 1281839 A01
```

A second step, not essential but easy and convenient, would be to remove spaces at the beginning and end of each line and extra spaces between words. You could do that by replacing matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
^ +| +$| (?= )
```

This regex performs the following operations.

```
^[ ]+    : match 1+ spaces at the beginning of a line
|        : or
[ ]+$    : match  1+ spaces at the end of a line
|        : or
[ ]      : match one space
(?= )    : use a positive lookahead to assert the space is followed
           by another space
```

Note that to make spaces show up in the above I expressed some as character classes containing a space.

That would convert the above strings to the following strings.

```
1234567 A00 7654321 B00 C00 1357913 1337335 A00
1234567 A00 7654321 B00 C00 1357913 1337335 A00
1337336 A00 1337338 A00 1337339 A00
1281660 A01 1281661 B00 1281839 A01
A01 1281660 1281661 B00 A01 1281839
A01 1281660 B00 1281661 1281839 A01
```

One can now use the following regular expression to match each pair of 7-digits numbers and revision numbers in each string. The 7-digit number will be saved to capture group 1, and capture group 4 will be empty (i.e., will hold an empty string), or vice-versa. The revision number will be saved to capture group 2 and capture group 3 will be empty, or vice-versa.

```
(?<![^ \n])(?:(?=\d{7} )(\d{7}) ([A-Z]\d{2})|([A-Z]\d{2}) (\d{7}))
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/kYEJSG/1/) | [R code](https://rextester.com/MISK78179)

This regular expression performs the following operations.

```
(?<![^ \n])     : negative lookbehind asserts that current position cannot
                : be preceded by a character other than a space or newline 
(?:             : begin non-capture group
  (?=\d{7} )    : positive lookahead asserts that current position is
                  followed by 7 digits
  (\d{7})       : match 7 digits, save to capture group 1 
  [ ]           : match one space           
  ([A-Z]\d{2})  : match an uppercase letter then 2 digits, save to
                  capture group 2
|               : or
  ([A-Z]\d{2})  : match an uppercase letter then 2 digits, save to
                  capture group 3
  (\d{7})       : match 7 digits, save to capture group 4
)               : end non-capture group
```

By replacing matches with the string `"\\1\\4 \\2\\3"` the following strings are produced:

```
1234567 A00 7654321 B00 1357913 C00 1337335 A00
1234567 A00 7654321 B00 1357913 C00 1337335 A00
1337336 A00 1337338 A00 1337339 A00
1281660 A01 1281661 B00 1281839 A01
1281660 A01 1281661 B00 1281839 A01
1281660 A01 1281661 B00 1281839 A01
```

You may of course want to save the results to an object other than a string, in which case I expect the approach taken here could be easily modified to satisfy requirements.

Comment: Thanks Cary. I ran your regex and it gets me close to where I need to be. I need to study this for some time.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions or require any changes to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a regular expression that looks for "Letter + 2 digits" + "7 digits" or the same thing swapped. For the examples provided this works:

```
s = "1234567 Rev A00 7654321 B00 Rev C00 1357913 1337335 Rev A00, 1337336
1234567 Rev A00 some random text 7654321 B00 Rev C00 1357913 1337335 Rev A00
1337336 Rev A00, 1337338 Rev. A00, and 1337339 REV A00
1281660 A01, 1281661 B00,1281839 A01
A01 1281660 1281661 B00 A01 1281839
Rev A01 1281660, REV. B00 1281661, 1281839 A01"

library(stringr)

z = str_match_all(s, "([A-Z]\\d{2}.+?\\d{7}|\\d{7}.+?[A-Z]\\d{2})")
```

This returns:

```
> z
[[1]]
      [,1]               [,2]              
 [1,] "1234567 Rev A00"  "1234567 Rev A00" 
 [2,] "7654321 B00"      "7654321 B00"     
 [3,] "C00 1357913"      "C00 1357913"     
 [4,] "1337335 Rev A00"  "1337335 Rev A00" 
 [5,] "1234567 Rev A00"  "1234567 Rev A00" 
 [6,] "7654321 B00"      "7654321 B00"     
 [7,] "C00 1357913"      "C00 1357913"     
 [8,] "1337335 Rev A00"  "1337335 Rev A00" 
 [9,] "1337336 Rev A00"  "1337336 Rev A00" 
[10,] "1337338 Rev. A00" "1337338 Rev. A00"
[11,] "1337339 REV A00"  "1337339 REV A00" 
[12,] "1281660 A01"      "1281660 A01"     
[13,] "1281661 B00"      "1281661 B00"     
[14,] "1281839 A01"      "1281839 A01"     
[15,] "A01 1281660"      "A01 1281660"     
[16,] "1281661 B00"      "1281661 B00"     
[17,] "A01 1281839"      "A01 1281839"     
[18,] "A01 1281660"      "A01 1281660"     
[19,] "B00 1281661"      "B00 1281661"     
[20,] "1281839 A01"      "1281839 A01"
```

Do `z[[1]][,1]` to return the first column.

You can try more cases at [this Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aIOrbg/1) (it's in PHP, but the only difference is that in R you need double backslashes `\\` instead of one `\`).

Comment: Thanks! Tested this and works well except for the condition where there is text between the part number and the revision. For instance: `1234567,SOME,TEXT,THAT CONTAINS ANYTHING BUT PN  Rev B00`. The regex matches all the text between the PN and the revision.

Comment: You can do a `str_replace` on the result to remove unwanted text.